# Django folder without registering it as an app

Tags: django

RoR dev learning Django here.

I've inherited a Django project, and I've learned that we can have apps, to encapsulate functionality. To do so I have to create an app like this:

`django-admin startapp my_app`

and then add the app to `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_project.my_app',
)
```

This works fine.

However I have found some folders in this Django project for example named:

```
/my_feature
```

that has its own `urls.py` file and models and views files, just like an app.
The `my_feature` functionalities work just fine. Requests are routed, views called, etc...

However, they are NOT present in `settings.py` as an app. `my_feature` is nowhere to be found in `INSTALLED_APPS` or anywhere else (searched the entire project and nothing).

So how is this working without it being registered as an app? If a folder with models and views and routes can just be placed in Django project root and will "just work", why are we taught it must be added to `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: They don't. Could be some dynamic loading. Instead of looking into the settings file, inspect `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` in a `python manage.py shell` after importing `from django.conf import settings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the details of installed apps:

- urls and views are driven by themselves, starting with ROOT_URLCONF which is loaded by the resolver, which is driven by the WSGIHandler.
- anything you can import that doesn't (indirectly) import any of the stuff below, you can import and use without being in INSTALLED_APPS
- Templates, static files, template tag libraries ("custom tags"), models and any initialization code you might need such as signal registration requires being in INSTALLED_APPS in order to be found. This is all driven by the [apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/) framework.

A grey area: you can register template tag library in other places, but having the app in INSTALLED_APPS will ensure it's loaded automatically.

Initialization code should be done in [`ready()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready).

### The reason:

Models and template libraries can be referenced by string:

```py
class Pizza(models.Model):
 # Reference to app bakery, with model that lowercases to topping
    topping = models.ForeignKey('bakery.topping')
```

```html
{# Reference to a template library in some app,
for which the name is globally unique within the project #}
{% load mytags %}
```

Templates and static files, need to be resolved using a set of base directories. Both can be configured as a separate list, but the apps framework also looks for subdirectories "static" and "templates" in each registered app and adds them to the resolver.

Comment: This is a djangorestframework project. Inside the ```/myfeature``` folder there ARE urls, views and serializer files. Models files are present but empty. Models are imported in this folder's views like this ```from users.models import StandardUser```. In this case is your answer still correct? This functionality can be installed without being registered in INSTALLED_APP ?

Comment: Yes, since the models in users are in a different app, the requirement to be in an "installed app" lies with the users app. "myfeature" is merely a python package that implements Django functionality and follows the structure of an Django app, but does not have entities that require integration with the apps framework. Views use serializers, serializers use models. As long as those models are somewhere else, you don't need to make your API an "app".